# Directional derivative confusion about terminology

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am confused about a definition of directional derivatives I found in the MIT Deep Learning book.

> The directional derivative in direction $u$ (a unit vector) is the slope of the
> function $f$ in direction $u$. In other words, the directional derivative is the derivative
> of the function $f (x + \alpha u)$ with respect to $\alpha$, evaluated at $\alpha = 0$.
> Using the chain rule, we can see that $ \frac \partial {\partial \alpha} f(x + \alpha u) $
> evaluates to $u^T \nabla_{x} f(x)$ when $ \alpha = 0$

I understand the first sentence but I don't understand what they are trying to say after that.

### What I know:

1. If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the directional derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ in the direction of the vector $v$ is defined as the limit $$D_v f(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+hv)-f(x_0)}{h}.$$
2. Some people use $ \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}$ to talk about $f'(x)$

### What I am confused about:

1. 

> derivative of the function $f (x + \alpha u)$ with respect to $\alpha$

For me this sentence means that we have another function $g(\alpha) = f (x + \alpha u)$ and then compute the derivative of $g$ with respect to $\alpha$

$$ g'(\alpha) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {g(\alpha + h) - g(\alpha)} h = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f (x + (\alpha + h) u) - f (x + \alpha u)} h $$

But I don't see how this is equivalent to the definition with $D_v f(x_0)$.

2. Where does $u^T$ come from and what does this $\nabla_{x} f(x)$ even mean? Is it just the partial derivative with respect to $x$?
3. I only the chain rule written in terms of functions $(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$ I don't understand what chain rule they are applying there.

Please be patient with me, I am just trying to understand how to reason about directional derivatives.

Comment: Answer to your 1.: you forgot the end of their sentence "derivative
of the function $f (x + \alpha u)$ with respect to $\alpha$, **evaluated at $\alpha = 0$**."

Comment: Answer to your 2.: $u^T$ is the row version of the column-vector $u$, and $\nabla_xf(x)$, which should better be denoted simply by $\nabla f(x)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $x$, i.e. the column-version of the row-matrix $Jf(x)$ of $Df(x)$.

Comment: Yes you are right, if I evaluate at $\alpha = 0$ it works!

Comment: Can you also explain how the chain rule is applied?

Comment: Answer to your 3.: The chain rule is applied to $g=f\circ h$ where $h(\alpha)=x+\alpha u$. So, $g'(0)=f'(x)\circ h'(0)$. Here, the linear maps $h'(0)$ and $g'(0)$, defined on $\Bbb R$, are identified respectively to $h'(0)(1)=u$ and $g'(0)(1)=f'(x)(u)$.

Comment: Is $Df(x)$ is equal to a column vector that shows the rate of change of $f$ with respect to each $x_i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151128/discussion-between-filat-nicolae-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: $Df(x)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to (supposedly) $\Bbb R$. Its matrix (in the canonical bases) is the row matrix $Jf(x)$ ([Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)) whose entries are the partial derivatives w.r.t. each $x_i$. The [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) $\nabla f(x)=Jf(x)^T$ is the corresponding column vector.

Comment: So $Df(x)$ has size $1 * n$ but the gradient has size $n * 1$ ?

Comment: $Df(x)$ has no size, it is a linear map. Its matrix $Jf(x)$ has size $1\times n$ indeed, hence its transpose $\nabla f(x)$ has size $n\times 1$. So, $$u^T\nabla f(x)=Jf(x)u=Df(x)(u).$$

Comment: Ah I see,  $Df(x)$ is a function. Sorry, now I understand. Thank you

Comment: One last question, I could also write this:

$ \frac \partial {\partial \alpha} f(x + \alpha u)  =  \frac \partial {\partial x + \alpha u} f(x + \alpha u) * \frac  {\partial x + \alpha u} \alpha = Df(x + \alpha u) * u $
And when I evaluate at $\alpha = 0$ I get $Df(x) * u$

Comment: Yes, but I don't like the notation $\frac \partial {\partial x + \alpha u} $. I prefer: $$\frac{ \partial f(x + \alpha u) }{\partial \alpha} =  Df(x +\alpha u) \left( \frac  {\partial (x + \alpha u)}{\partial \alpha}\right)=Df(x +\alpha u)(u),$$ so $$\frac{ \partial f(x + \alpha u) }{\partial \alpha}(0)=Df(x )(u),$$ (I put parenthesis around $u$ because a map is applied to it. I you prefer to write a matrix product, replace $Df$ by $Jf$.)